# Pulumi: "pulumi plugin install resource kubernetes" fails

Tags: go, kubernetes, pulumi

I have a little Go app which creates YAML ressources for me I then deploy to a Kubernetes cluster.

It worked quite well but since some hours (?) it fails saying:

> error: Could not automatically download and install resource plugin 'pulumi-resource-kubernetes', install the plugin using `pulumi plugin install resource kubernetes`.
> Underlying error: 401 HTTP error fetching plugin from https://api.github.com/repos/pulumi/pulumi-kubernetes/releases/latest

Executing `pulumi plugin install resource kubernetes` manually returns the same result:

> error: 401 HTTP error fetching plugin from https://api.github.com/repos/pulumi/pulumi-kubernetes/releases/latest

I have no idea what's wrong; I don't really get the message and more detail is not available - as far as I can see. The link (https://api.github.com/repos/pulumi/pulumi-kubernetes/releases/latest) seems to work properly. If a GitHub API throttle is the reason, I don't see where to place an API key.

I am running MacOS Ventura 13.1 (22C65) on a MacBook Pro 2019. No recent changes here. Go has version 1.19 and the lib is github.com/pulumi/pulumi-kubernetes/sdk/v3 v3.24.1

Any hint is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share any details about the runtime environment (like OS, version, etc.) and whether it's possible that's changed? It if were an API throttle, setting the `GITHUB_TOKEN` environment variable would likely fix it, but in that case I'd expect to see a 403 rather than a 401.

Comment: I also started seeing this issue pop up, but for the AWS plugin. I guess that GitHub has changed some behavior recently.

Comment: @ChristianNunciato: Thanks for the note, I added the version info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue can be solved by providing a valid GitHub API token via the `GITHUB_TOKEN` environment variable.

Thanks a lot ***Christian Nunciato*** for the hint.

However, if anybody knows some background about this and why this happened so surprisingly, I would be very interested in some insights/explanations.

Comment: Glad that helped! At this point it seems like GitHub has just gotten a bit more restrictive with regard to its API limits. We've been hearing increasing reports of this (and even experiencing it ourselves) for the last few months.